# vendor.js bundle in fusebox not working

Tags: fusebox

I'm configuring my angular app with fusebox instead of webpack and I want to have 3 separated bundles (polyfills.js, vendor.js and app.js).

In webpack I'm using this:

```
'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
'app': './src/main.ts'
```

being polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
  // Production
} else {
  // Development and test
  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

and vendor.ts

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/compiler';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
import '@angular/forms';

import 'rxjs';
import './rxjs-extensions';
```

with rxjs-extensions.ts

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Now I changed this to fusebox

```
fuse.bundle('polyfills').instructions('> polyfills.ts');
fuse.bundle('vendor').instructions('~ main.ts vendor.ts');
fuse.bundle('app').instructions('!> [main.ts]').watch().hmr();
```

In this case polyfills is fine, and vender has all 3rd party dependencies from the app (~main.ts) plus all in vendor.ts, while app has only what is in the project.

It seems to compile fine but then when I execute the code I get a `ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function` in my service.get(...).map()

My feeling is that vendor.ts is not importing rxjs-extensions.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

If I use just

```
fuse.bundle('polyfills').instructions('> polyfills.ts');
fuse.bundle('vendor').instructions('> vendor.ts');
fuse.bundle('app').instructions('> main.ts').watch().hmr();
```

it works, but then my app.js bundle includes too many things and goes from 303K to 2.4MB

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got the order right. Try [WebIndexPlugin](http://fuse-box.org/page/configuration#configuration) it helps to automatically inject scripts. If you post your configuration file it might be able to tell you what's wrong